# How to get the target(s) for a PBXFileReference in Xcodeproj

Tags: ruby, xcode, xcode-project, xcodeproj

I'm attempting to write a Ruby script that will delete certain files from the Xcode project. I can find the files based on the absolute path and remove them from the project using the [`remove_from_project`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/xcodeproj/Xcodeproj/Project/Object/PBXFileReference#remove_from_project-instance_method) method of `PBXFileReference`. However this leaves source files (e.g. `.m` or `.swift` files) in the "Compile Sources" build phase of whatever target(s) it is a member of, but without a name.

[image]

I know I need to also remove the file from the target(s) but there seems to be no easy link between a `PBXFileReference` and a target ([`PBXNativeTarget`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/xcodeproj/Xcodeproj/Project/Object/PBXNativeTarget)).

From what I can make out I need to iterate through each of the project's targets, then iterate through the [`files`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/xcodeproj/Xcodeproj/Project/Object/AbstractBuildPhase#files-instance_method) or [`files_references`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/xcodeproj/Xcodeproj/Project/Object/AbstractBuildPhase#files_references-instance_method) of that target's [`source_build_phase`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/xcodeproj/Xcodeproj/Project/Object/PBXNativeTarget#source_build_phase-instance_method) looking for the `PBXFileReference` I already have.

Is this correct or am I missing some obvious link such e.g. `file_ref.target_memberships`?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @lemonlimepomelo unfortunately not, I ended up working around it by iterating over each target's files and looking for a match. Dirty but it works. https://github.com/NxSoftware/stronglyboards/blob/master/lib/stronglyboards.rb#L105

Answer (score 0):

```
if (object.is_a?(Xcodeproj::Project::Object::PBXFileReference))
    if (!object.real_path.exist?)
        object.remove_from_project
    end
end

project.save(project_path)
```

Comment: Code only answers become tremendously more useful if you add an explanation about how your code answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure when this was introduced, but as of `xcodeproj` version 1.15.0, you can can get the build files associated with a file reference with:

```
file_ref.build_files
```

From the [documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj/Xcodeproj%2FProject%2FObject%2FPBXFileReference:build_files):

> **Method: Xcodeproj::Project::Object::PBXFileReference#build_files**
>
> `#build_files ⇒ Array<PBXBuildFile>`
>
> Returns the build files associated with the current file reference.
>
> Returns:
>   `(Array<PBXBuildFile>)` — the build files associated with the current file reference.

Seems like this should do the trick:

```
file_ref.build_files.each { |file| file.remove_from_project }
```